# Is there a cross-platform solution to interacting with node OS when using selenium grid?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, remote-access, autoit

I wrote some selenium tests that were run and passed locally.  I wrote them for Windows/Chrome.  At one point, my app opens up a local file explorer to upload a file.  To interact with this I used AutoIt, which solved my problem.  However, now I am moving my tests to grid (through lambdatest) and I am testing on both Windows and Mac.  AutoIt only works on Windows, and out of the box it only works locally.  I know some solutions have been offered to use AutoIt remotely, but this doesn't help me with Mac OS.

Is there a general solution for how to approach interacting with a remote machine during a selenium test?

Any help is appreciated.  I'm not sure how to approach this.

EDIT:
After looking around at a lot of solutions to this, the below is what I have been trying but the test times out because it cannot find the file input.  I know there must be some way to do this.  People testing apps on MacOS can't use AutoIT, so what is the solution?

```
        # upload photo
        photo_upload_element = wait1.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'reply-field__button--cam'))).click()
        time.sleep(2)
        file_input = self.driver1.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='file']")
        time.sleep(2)
        file_input.send_keys(DIR_PATH + r"\path\to\local\photo.jpg")
        time.sleep(2)
        file_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)
        wait1.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'buttons-grid__button'))).click()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Here is the html on the page for the input:

```
<template>
  <input
    class="fileselect"
    v-on:change="handleFileSelect"
    ref="fileinput"
    id="cam"
    type="file"
    accept="image/*"
    :capture="camera"
    data-testid="fileselect"
  />
</template>
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?
[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that sending the file path to the form's <input type="file"> tag isn't working here.  You might consider converting to Java and using Java's robot for this.  Those solutions are always a little wonky though cross platform... if you can get the webmaster to change the code to allow for a manual form submission you'll have an easier time of it. (Selenium does have a .submit() method for submitting forms, so you won't necessary need a submit button...)  Also check this topic: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test

Comment: Are you trying to solve the browser popping up problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you use the `file detector` is implemented when running tests on the grid that should take care of this kind of issue.

You can refer to the below link for more information on the file detector.
[File Detector in Remoter Driver implementation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html)

I think we don't have to use AutoIT in this case, as the input type is `file` ideally `send_keys` method should take care of browsing the file.

Comment: Due to `type="file"` and `data-testid="fileselect"` you can't do `send_keys()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to manage the browse file issue. If so, you can use `pyautogui`:

```
from pyautogui import typewrite

typewrite('file.txt')

typewrite(['enter'])
```